# SAT Sentence Completion Question

Tags: exam-questions

Objective: Fill in the blanks for the sentence.

The sound advice given by the eleventh-century medical scholar Trotula in her writings on women's health ------- some of our assumptions about the inadequacy of medieval medicine.

**(A)   belies**
(B) bypasses
**your answer(C)    elucidates**
(D) compounds
(E) camouflages

The correct answer is A. but I think C. because the Trotula explains the assumptions to clarify any misconceptions on the medicine.

Comment: The sound advice contradicts our assumptions, so you need a verb that shows contradiction as such, and only *belies* works, among the given choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've rewritten the sentence more simply, putting in some synonyms of `belies`:

The good medical advice given by Trotula `contradicts` / `is at odds with` / `calls into question` / `proves to be false` our assumptions that medieval medicine was bad.

The correct answer is `belies` because reality contradicted our expectations. To use `elucidate` in a similar sentence, I might say:

The fact that life expectancy in medieval Britain was 35 years old `elucidates` our assumptions about that period's unsanitary living conditions.

I can use `elucidates` here because our expectations match reality.